# Prophets cannot sin?

Tags: source-identification, sin, prophets, bible, infallability

I was learning about [Sa'adyah Gaon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saadia_Gaon)'s approach to various Biblical stories and came across this statement (footnote 37 [here](http://alhatorah.org/Endangering_Sarai_in_Egypt/2), bolded by me for emphasis):

> S. Stuber, in his article, "מפגשי בראשית – בין אברהם למושלי הארצות", in ספר היובל לרב מרדכי ברויאר (Jeruslaem, 1992): 129-146, **identifies these heretics as the surrounding Muslims. They claimed that this story was a forgery inserted into the Torah, for it is inconceivable that a prophet could lie.**

A similar statement is repeated [here](http://alhatorah.org/Sin_of_the_Golden_Calf/2) (bolded by me for emphasis):

> Polemical motivations – R. Saadia's full-throated defense of Aharon's actions may be partially motivated by an attempt to counter **Muslim claims that passages in the Torah which portray sins of prophets are forged insertions**.

Is it true that Muslims believe that a prophet cannot sin, and that any bible passage that says so must be incorrect/a later insertion? Please provide sources if possible, and thanks in advance!